# Node.js multiline input

Tags: node.js, keypress, readline, eof, command-line-interface

I'd like to prompt the user for input, let the user enter multiple lines of text, hitting enter between each line, then terminate the input by pressing CTRL+D or some such thing.

With "keypress", I can catch the EOF, but I would have to handle all the echoing, backspace handling, terminal escape sequences, etc. manually.  It would be much better if I could use "readline", but somehow intercept the CTRL+D (EOF) with "keypress", but I'm not sure how I would go about that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the [`line`](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_line) and [`close`](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_close) events:

```
var readline = require('readline');

var input = [];

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.prompt();

rl.on('line', function (cmd) {

    input.push(cmd);
});

rl.on('close', function (cmd) {

    console.log(input.join('\n'));
    process.exit(0);
});
```

Comment: Commands such as git also open a default editor for user input. Is this also possible with Node?

Answer (score 2):

The `@inquirer/editor` package does a great job this

It opens the user's default editor for input

For example

```
import editor from '@inquirer/editor';

const story = await editor({
  message: "Tell me a story",
  waitForUseInput: true,
  postfix: '.md',
})
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@inquirer/editor