# how to use readLine() to read line by line in input using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, input, stdin, readline, stdio

my Input is like this

```
5
1
2
3
7
2
```

how can i use readLine() to read line by line when i try `var line = readLine();`
only the first line can be read which is 5

Comment: From where do you read to read the input? This won't work in browser. Are you using node-js?

Comment: With node-js, you can try this solution maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350256/node-js-multiline-input

Comment: @henrik123 im not using Node-Js

Comment: because im trying to take a challenge in code forces and my language shoule be JavaScript version 8